# How can I make a div height automatically fit screen and expands if the content exceeds height

Tags: html, css

On my web page I have a div that expands(height) to fit the size of the screen.

Here is my CSS:

```
.round-cornerapp {
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; 
      -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
      -o-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
      border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
     background-color: #C2C2BD;
     height:100vh;
     padding-top: .5cm;

   }
```

I would like the div to adjust automatically if the content extends the size of the screen.

I have tried the following:

```
.round-cornerapp {
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; 
      -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
      -o-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
      border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
     background-color: #C2C2BD;
     height:100vh;
     height:auto;
     padding-top: .5cm;

   }
```

The height does not extend automatically with the above unless I remove height: 100vh at which point the height no longer fits the screen depending on the content of the div.

How can I make the Div fit the size of my screen even when empty and automatically expands in height  as divs are added

Comment: try to use a percentage value for the height
(height: 50%; /*or any suitable value*/)

Comment: you can also try min-height: 100vh , I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Your last comment worked

Comment: @user1526912 can I add this comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery more specifically, the `$(document).height()` function.

```
$('.divFullScreen').height($(document).height());
```

Otherwise, you could also use CSS as follows.

```
.divFullScreen {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

PS: your `div`'s class should be `divFullScreen` for this to work.